# PHP hangs on a loop and never makes Request

Tags: php, rest, oop

I have a RESTful API that I need to inteact with using CURL. I have created a wrapper class that has a static function with the CURL code.

```
class ApiInvoke
{

    public static function execute($username, $password, $endpoint, $data = array(), $options = array())
    {
       //Rest of the CURL code goes here.....
    }
 }
```

I the created a class where I call the static APIInvokve class method to actually execute the API call. Below is the consumer class for ApiInvoke class above.

require "api_invoke.php"

```
 class FlowgearConnect
 {

    //Properties go gere

    public function getResults($model, $workflow, $data)
    {

       $endpoint = $this->getEndpoint($model, $workflow);

       $results = array();

       if(!is_null($endpoint)){

          $results = ApiInvoke::execute('username', 'password', $endpoint, $data array('timeout' => 30));
       }

      return $results;
    }

   //....
 }
```

Then I have a ParentClass class that create an instance of FlowgearConnect object which is made avalable to sub-classes. However, all subclasses are are processed inside the same parent class.

```
class ParentClass
{
  private $Flowgear;

  public function init()
  {
     $this->Flowgear = new FlowGearConnect(); //Assuming it has been required somewhere
  }
}
```

Then we may have ChildClassA and ChildClassB which extends ParentClass. By vartue of the child classes extending the parent class they have access to the instance of $this->Flowgear object already because below is how the FlowgearConnect class is used:

```
class ChildClassA
{

  public function getResults()
  {
    $results = $this->Flowgear->getResults('child_a', 'latestEvents', array());
   }

 }
```

ChildClassB has the very same function or rather exact except it might be responsible for getting a list of orders for example.

How these child classes are processed inside the parent class is depicted below:

```
 //A function inside the ParentClass to process ChildClassA and ChildClassB
 public function processModules()
 {
   $modules = $request->getModules(); 

   foreach($modules as $module){

      require_once "modules/' . $module;

      $Module = new $module();
      $Module ->getResults();
   }
}
```

Something along these lines is not right.... Basically the extending class creates an instance of a class that is used by child classes. Somewhere somehow something is not right here and I guess it has everything to do with the facy that I am not using singgleton. I could if I new how to where CURL is concerned.

Comment: I think we need a little more code than that.

Comment: I'm going to need to see the inner workings of that class.

Comment: I have just came across this link http://raynux.com/blog/2009/06/13/http-client-class-for-php-development/ and its actually what I want to achieve. I will look into the code and see if I can do something similar because eventually I want to be able to have a single instance of my Flowgear object and create multiple objects at will.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid of me to ever thought I could never be able to create just one instance of a curl object thanks to Rayhan’s Http Client class (http://raynux.com/blog/2009/06/13/http-client-class-for-php-development/).

Basically what I wanted was to create a CURL SINGLETON class such that I do not have instances of the same object created over and over again.

Below is a skeleton of how I went about to achieve this:

```
class Flowgear
{
  static private $_instance;

  //Rest properties here...


  public function __cosntsruct()
  { $this->_token = $this->_username .':'. $this->_passoword; }

  public function execute()
  {
    //Call a class that handles the actual API invocation passing all relevant data
  }

  static public function &getInstance()
  {
    if(self::$_instance == null){
       self::$_instance = new self;
     }

    return self::$_instance;
  }
}
```

Then I simply get a single instance of the class by calling Flowgear::getInstance();

Comment: Two points. In php, objects are passed by reference by default, so no need for `&` in `getInstance`. Also, this whole thing is considered an anti-pattern, as it is nothing more that a glorified `global`.

Comment: Thanks for the first point. I have chosen the use of Singleton because I am working with a legacy code and I wanted my changes to be exactly the same as the database singleton that is used in the code. Thanks for the feedback @TwiStar